# RoboCopy giving error in universal file path

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, scripting, robocopy

I am conducting some Arduino HID research.
I was trying to set my Leo to open powershell and make a back up of all the .pdfs in my Documents folders to a flash drive by volume name.

I want this to be portable to different machines. So a specified file path that includes a username can not be used.

The original script I found is this one.

```
    param([parameter(mandatory=$true)]$VolumeName,
      [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$SrcDir)

# find connected backup drive:
$backupDrive = $null
get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | % {
    if ($_.VolumeName -eq $VolumeName) {
        $backupDrive = $_.DeviceID
    }
}
if ($backupDrive -eq $null) {
    throw "$VolumeName drive not found!"
}

# mirror 
$backupPath = $backupDrive + "\"
& robocopy.exe $SrcDir $backupPath /MIR /Z
```

The Problem I am having is that when I pass the path of `C:\users\$env:username\Documents\`
Powershell throws an error stating.

```
"ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."
```

Next i tried removing the $srcDIR parameter and specifying the path in a variable with the new script looking like this:

```
param([parameter(mandatory=$true)]$VolumeName)
 $backupDrive = $null
 get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | % {
   if ($_.VolumeName -eq $VolumeName) {
       $backupDrive = $_.DeviceID
    }
 } 
 $backupPath = $backupDrive + "\"

$source=@($env:username + "\Documents\")
$destination=@($backupPath)

robocopy $source  $destination *.pdf /mir /z
```

That failed as well giving me the another path error apparently robocopy is imputing my username twice seen here:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Tuesday, August 15, 2017 3:49:04 AM
   Source : C:\Users\me\me\Documents\
     Dest = F:\

    Files : *.pdf

  Options : /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /Z /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2017/08/15 03:49:04 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Accessing Source Directory C:\Users\damav\damav\Documents\
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So I edited the last line to include a direct path and no varible.

```
robocopy C:\Users\$env:username\Documents\  $backupDrive *.pdf /mir /z
```

The output gave a different results that confuses me more than the rest of the issues. Have a look:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Tuesday, August 15, 2017 3:55:36 AM
   Source : C:\Users\me\Documents\
     Dest = F:\

    Files : *.pdf

  Options : /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /Z /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           0    C:\Users\me\Documents\
                           0    C:\Users\me\Documents\My Music\
          New Dir          0    C:\Users\me\Documents\My Pictures\
2017/08/15 03:55:36 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Time-Stamping Destination Directory F:\My Pictures\
Access is denied.
Waiting 30 seconds... Retrying...
2017/08/15 03:56:07 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Time-Stamping Destination Directory F:\My Pictures\
Access is denied.
Waiting 30 seconds...
```

The reason why it is so confusing is because these directories that robocopy tried to copy do not exist within my documents folder nor flash drive.
C:\Users\me\Documents\

C:\Users\me\Documents\My Music\
                   C:\Users\me\Documents\My Pictures\
                   F:\My Pictures\

So i am completely stumped and came here to ask the pros for some assistance.
I have also tried `%USERNAME%` and `%USERPROFILE%` in the file path using the same script variations i stated above but that didn't work either due to robocopy assuming they was part of the actual path name. `I.E. C:users\%USERPROFILE%\Documents`

So to conclude I need to be able to plug a named volume flash drive into my pc.
Insert my Arduino have it type out a command in CMD, POWERSHELL, or create a .ps1 in notepad but the issue i am having is with the source directory path not being recognized when not using a specific user name in the path which is not possible due to my need to have this portable across machines and users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue 1:
>   The Problem I am having is that when I pass the path of C:\users\$env:username\Documents\ Powershell throws an error stating.

Just assuming, but this sounds like an issue on how you transmit your path. Take look at following code:

```
'C:\users\$env:username\Documents\'
"C:\users\$env:username\Documents\"
```

Both lines are generating a string, but only the second one "translates" to the correct path. Powershell differentiates between normal quotes (") and single quotes ('). See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Quoting_Rules?view=powershell-5.1) for more information.

The script works completely fine on my test using the normal quotes for the source directory.

> Issue 2:
>   Next i tried removing the $srcDIR parameter and specifying the path in a variable with the new script looking like this:
>   That failed as well giving me the another path error apparently robocopy is imputing my username twice seen here:

Your issue here is $env:username only contains your username, depending on where you start your script your code would behave differently. Starting from C:\users\me it translates  to C:\users\me\me\documents, would you be in C:\users it would have translated to C:\uses\me\documents and it could have worked. Instead of a hard coded path with the $env:username I would use:

```
"$env:USERPROFILE\Documents"
```

> Issue 3:
>   The reason why it is so confusing is because these directories that robocopy tried to copy do not exist within my documents folder nor flash drive. C:\Users\me\Documents\

The robocopy error tells you that it can't write on your target, could be a permission/file system (NTFS to FAT32?) issue. Make sure that you can write on your flash drive.
e.g. try first to write without a powershell script just use robocopy directly

```
robocopy C:\users\me\Documents\ F:\ *.pdf /MIR /Z
```

Comment: Concerning the quotes. In my acutal script no quotes are attached to the file path. The quotes were only for the post. I should have been more clear. When you say the script runs fine fore you. Are you giving $SrcDir and exact file path i.e. C:users/yourusername/ or did you pass $SrcDir the parameters $env:username or %USERPROFILE%

Comment: You answered it with the 2nd issue / statement. it's so obvious now that you have pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the registry key for short files names as part of the cleanup suggested in the Best Practice Analyzer. The key it told me to modify was this one.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\  NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation
```

It was defaulted to 2 and I had changed it to 1 as per the BPA. I went back and changed it back to 2 and reran the robocopy script without errors.

Just wanted to let people know what worked for me:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem  /v NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

My Windows 10 1909 (18363.778) was defaulted 0. I just set 2 and now it works like a charm.